# Flutter: customize where navigator opens up from in widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

For my Flutter project, I am using `StreamBuilder` on the `MaterialApp` to detect any changes:

From `DevTools`: Widget Tree

```
MyApp
  -- MaterialApp
        -- StreamBuilder
             --Page 1
```

Now, from `page 1`, I click a button to navigate to a `page 2` using the following:

```
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => Page_2()
    );
```

When I check the DevTools, the widget tree is following:

```
MyApp
  -- MaterialApp
        |-- Page 2
        |
        |-- StreamBuilder
             --Page 1
```

Now, `page 2` is no longer inside of the `StreamBuilder`.

Page 2 is called from Page 1, but it is not a part of the `StreamBuilder.

Is there a way to dictate which parent widget the navigator opens up from?

Comment: For every new person with this issue: I had the same problem and solved it using nested Navigator. You can see how the tree now looks like in my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330877/how-to-open-new-materialpageroute-as-a-child-in-widget-tree-in-flutter